# Cassandra date range selection to giving data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I'm facing an issue with my cassandra query for getting data in a specific datetime range.
My query goes as follows

```
select * from table1 where column1='abc' and time>='2015-11-13 10:43:55' and time<='2015-11-13 11:48:14'
```

If I execute this query, it is giving out no data.

However if I execute the query below (time greater than), I get the data

```
select * from table1 where column1='abc' and time>='2015-11-13 10:43:55'
```

But if the execute the query below (time less than), I won't get data.

```
select * from table1 where colimn1='abc' and time<='2015-11-13 11:48:14'
```

I'm suspecting the glitch is in less than time.

Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your table data, but I do have a thought based on experience...

How did you save your `time` timestamp values initially?  Did you insert the timestamps without milliseconds?  Or did you use `dateof(now())`?

I'd be curious to see the output of:

```
SELECT column1, time, blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(time)) FROM table1
WHERE column1='abc' AND time>'2015-11-13 10:43:55';
```

In the `blobAsBigint(timestampAsBlob(time))` column are your last 3 digits zeros?  If they are not, then your `time` values have milliseconds present.  Queries for a 2015-11-13 11:48:14 time with `time<='2015-11-13 11:48:14'` will not yield any results unless that value is *exactly* 2015-11-13 11:48:14.000.

The tricky part about using Cassandra timestamps as clustering keys, is that (by default) it will allow you to use *more* precision than it will actually show you in cqlsh.

Comment: The value for time is coming from a service and it is using java.util.Date for storing data. the datetype for for time column in timestamp...